# Python : value convert to columns and flag

Tags: python

Are there any ways to convert value to column name and flag them as 1 or 0 as per below example using python code?

hobbytable has value in hobby columns, but some cells have multiple values separated by "/".
In order to use multiple regression model or others, dataset would be better shape as below expected outcome.

It would be appreciated to share sample code to solve this problem.

hobbytable (CSV file)

```
personID, hobby
x1234, baseball/soccer
y1234, reading/baseball
z1234, null
a1234, soccer
```

expected outcome as DataFrame

```
personID, baseball, soccer, reading, soccer
x1234, 1, 1, 0, 0
y1234, 1, 0, 1, 0
z1234, 0, 0, 0, 0
a1234, 0, 1, 0, 0
```

Comment: What code have you tried to solve this please? can you share your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv(fileName, sep=",")
df2 = df1["hobby"].str.get_dummies("/")
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  personID             hobby  baseball  reading  soccer
0    x1234   baseball/soccer         1        0       1
1    y1234  reading/baseball         1        1       0
2    z1234               NaN         0        0       0
3    a1234            soccer         0        0       1
```

Comment: Thank you Soumendra! I will check to my actual data.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) to flag the values & `groupby` index to reduce the dataframe. [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) Concatenate created `dummies` with `original dataframe` along column index.

```
import pandas as pd

dummies = (
    pd.get_dummies(df.hoppy.str.split("/").explode())
        .groupby(level=0).sum()
)
print(pd.concat([df, dummies], axis = 1))
```

---

```
personID             hoppy  baseball  reading  soccer
0    x1234   baseball/soccer         1        0       1
1    y1234  reading/baseball         1        1       0
2    z1234               NaN         0        0       0
3    a1234            soccer         0        0       1
```

Comment: Nice, I am always amazed how many ways there are to solve a task.

Comment: Hi Sushanth! appreciate your help! let me try this to my code and will see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line:

```
df = df.assign(val=1).pivot_table(values='val', index='personID,', columns='hoppy').fillna(0)
```

---

**Explaination:**

`.assign()` adds a column, here we fill it with the 1 you later see in the output table

`.pivot_table()` now pivots the table essentialy doing the main work for you, if a persionID is not found for a column it will have a "nan" value

`.fillna()` is therefore used to fill this "nan" values with 0

Comment: Hi Andreas, Thank you for your quick answer. I will apply it.